# Showing author name from Author category in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop-1.7

I am creating a online book store using  prestashop. I created a category "Authors" at root level and added author names as sub-category to this. I created below function in `classes/product.php`,

```
public static function getProductCategoriesParent($id_product = '', $id_parent = '', $id_lang = null)
{
    if (!$id_lang)
        $id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id;

        $ret = array();
        $row = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS('
            SELECT cp.`id_category`, cl.`name`, cl.`link_rewrite` FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category` c ON (c.id_category = cp.id_category)
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang` cl ON (cp.`id_category` = cl.`id_category`'.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('cl').')
            '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('category', 'c').'
            WHERE cp.`id_product` = '.(int)$id_product.' AND c.`id_parent` = '.(int)$id_parent.' AND cl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang //<-- bug was in this line - originally there's cl.'id_parent'
        );

        foreach ($row as $val)
            $ret[$val['id_category']] = $val;

        return $ret;
    }
```

and added the below code in `product.tpl` template file,

```
<ul>
    {foreach from=Product::getProductCategoriesParent(Tools::getValue('id_product'),[52]) item=cat}
        <li><a href="{$link->getCategoryLink({$cat.id_category})}" title="{$cat.name}">{$cat.name}</a></li>
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

**52 being my category id**

but event after clearing cache from performance page, author names are not appearing. I tried using `var_dump()` function on `$product` object, but I did not find helpful in that object.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for with that

```
{foreach from=Product::getProductCategoriesParent(Tools::getValue('id_product'), 52) item=cat}
             <a href="{$link->getCategoryLink({$cat.id_category})}" title="{$cat.name}">{$cat.name|escape:'htmlall'|nl2br nofilter}</a>
{/foreach}
```